# Structure theorem of finite rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

Like structure theorem for finite abelian groups or modules over PID, is there any structure theorem for finite rings? Thanks.

Comment: Finite commutative rings or finite rings in general?

Comment: finite rings in general. thanks

Comment: For finite commutative rings look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305824/structure-of-finite-commutative-rings). In general, the question is similar to find a structure theorem for finite groups.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825661

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no known complete classification of finite rings.

In the following, I'm assuming a ring is unitary, but not necessarily commutative.

The first step is to see that the decomposition of the additive group into groups of pairwise coprime prime power orders is also a ring-theoretic decomposition. In this way, we get a unique decomposition of any finite ring into rings of prime power order. Hence it suffices to classify rings of order $p^n$ with $p$ prime.

For $n=1$, there is only the ring $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

For $n=2$, it's a nice exercise to show that up to isomorphism, there are the 4 rings $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb F_{p^2}$, $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2)$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/305512/61691) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/109506/61691).

The case $n = 3$ is already quite tedious. It can be found in Theorem 14 of the article [R. Raghavendran, *Finite Associative Rings*, Composito Mathematica **21** (1969), 195—229](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CM_1969__21_2_195_0). The result is that there are 11 rings of order 8 and 12 rings of order $p^3$ for $p$ an odd prime. The only non-commutative ring among them is the ring of upper $2\times 2$ triangular matrices over $\mathbb F_p$.

If I remember correctly, today the classification is known up to $p^5$ or $p^6$. It gets increasingly nasty, of course.

For some further classification-related properties of finite rings, see this [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44277/61691).

Comment: What do you mean by "primary decomposition" here?

Comment: And why does a decomposition of the additive group yield such a one for the ring?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Sorry, that was not correct, of course. What I thought of is: We decompose the additive group uniquely into groups of prime power order (one for each prime). This decomposition induces a decomposition as rings.