# Commutative rings of order $p^3$.

Tags: ring-theory

Does anyone know of a listing of all rings (or at least those that are commutative) of a given order?  In particular $p^3$, for a prime $p$.

Comment: Since a ring must be an abelian group, start by looking at all abelian group structures of order $p^3$.

Comment: It is not difficult to find all abelian groups of a given finite order. If the order you want is $p^3$, then there are $3$ distinct abelian groups (up to isomorphism). In each case, there are at least $2$ associative, commutative and distributive operations you can consider for multiplication. One is element-wise multiplication, and one is the trivial multiplication (all products are $0$). I don't know whether there are more.

Comment: @Arthur there are more, for instance, the field structure $\mathbb{F}_{p^3}$

Comment: do we require rings to have $1$?

Comment: For the commutative case, I would guess that taking direct products of $\mathbb{Z}/p^i$ with finite fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^j}$ would account for all of them but this is just a guess.

Comment: @MattB consider $R= \mathbb{F_3}[X]/(X^3 - 1)$. It isn't a field, but it has a unique prime ideal so it can't be a non-trivial product either.

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368323/structure-theorem-of-finite-rings